# My invertString function doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: c, algorithm

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIL8v.png)]

So, I have to solve the problem above. I have written some code in C, but the compiler doesn't give me any outputs. Here's the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void invertString(char *s1, char **s2);


void invertString(char *s1, char **s2){
    int len = strlen(s1);
    *s2 = (char*)malloc((len+1) * sizeof(char));
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while (end < len){
        while(s1[end]<s1[end+1] && end < len-1)
            end++;
        for (int i=end;i>=start;i--)
            (*s2)[index]=s1[i];
            index++;
        start = end + 1;
        while(s1[end]>=s1[end+1] && end < len-1){
            (*s2)[index]=s1[end];
            index++;
            end++;
            start = end;
        }

    }
    (*s2)[index] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    char s1[] = "A B C D D D D Z Y X W E F G";
    char *s2 = NULL;

    invertString(s1, &s2);

    printf("Input string: %s\n", s1);
    printf("Output string: %s\n", s2);

    free(s2);
    return 0;
}`
```

I was expecting the code to output the string such that the substrings in ascending order would be reversed to descending, while the rest of the string would remain the same. Instead, I receive no output. I think the function is stuck in a loop because when I try to re-run, it says the function is already running.

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code to track the flow of execution and evaluate the value of variables as the code runs. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to start learning. There is no better tool available to a programmer than the debugger to detect flaws in program logic and trace through to see exactly how the code is functioning at runtime.

Comment: The loop `for (int i=end;i>=start;i--)` has one statement, because it lacks `{` braces `}`. However the indentation of the next line suggests you intended it to be part of the loop. Adding braces to include those 2 lines doesn't fix the problem though.

Comment: You can also debug with print statements. For example add `printf("%d %d\n", end, len);` after the line `while (end < len){`

Comment: The outer loop `while (end < len)` never terminates (with or without the mentioned braces). Note that if the inner while loops don't run, `end` is never incremented. Adding `end++;` at the close of the outer `while` loop makes it end, but with the wrong answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on braces. I completely missed that! I debugged the code and turns out that the (end < len-1) statement in the inner while loops are the reason that the outer while loop never terminates. I fixed that but right now the output I get is "AABBCCDDDDDDDDZZYYXXWWEEFFGG". Will update if I find a solution.

Comment: BigWillieN, Please re-post the picture as text.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that because my input string had spaces between all letters, my traverser was completely useless. I had to either iterate +2 every time or delete all spaces in the input. This updated code works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void invertString(char *s1, char **s2);


void invertString(char *s1, char **s2){
    
    int len = strlen(s1);
    *s2 = (char*)malloc((len) * sizeof(char));
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while (end < len){
        printf("%d%d\n", end, len);
        while(s1[end]<s1[end+1])
            end++;
        for (int i=end;i>=start;i--){
            (*s2)[index]=s1[i];
            index++;
            }
        end++;
        start = end;
        while(s1[end]>=s1[end+1]){
            (*s2)[index]=s1[end];
            index++;
            end++;
            start = end;
            
            
        }
    }
    (*s2)[index] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    char s1[] = "ABCDDDDZYXWEFG";
    char *s2 = NULL;

    invertString(s1, &s2);

    printf("Input string: %s\n", s1);
    printf("Output string: %s\n", s2);

    free(s2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code accesses outside array bounds.

Viewable with some tests using OP's corrected code.

Last error certainly due to insufficient allocation.

```
// *s2 = (char*)malloc((len) * sizeof(char));
*s2 = malloc((len + 1u) * sizeof(char));
```

Note: `char` may be negative.

Perhaps additional errors.

```
void invertString(char *s1, char **s2){

    int len = strlen(s1);
    *s2 = (char*)malloc((len) * sizeof(char));
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while (end < len){
        printf("%d%d\n", end, len);
        while(s1[end]<s1[end+1])
            end++;
        for (int i=end;i>=start;i--){
            (*s2)[index]=s1[i];
            index++;
            }
        end++;
        start = end;
        if (end + 1 > len) {
          fprintf(stderr, "%d %d %d\n", __LINE__, end + 1, len);
          //exit(-1);
        }
        while(s1[end]>=s1[end+1]){
            (*s2)[index]=s1[end];
            index++;
            end++;
            start = end;


        }
    }
    if (index >= len) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%d %d %d\n", __LINE__, index, len);
      exit(-1);
    }

    (*s2)[index] = '\0';
}
```